# spring crudrepository save with specific id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, repository, spring-data-jpa

I want to insert(not update) data to my repository with specific id's, but whenever I do that Id's are ignored and the inserted entries have simply the next id in the sequence.

```
Entity entity = new Entity();
entity.setId(4l);
//..
Entity saved = repository.save(entity);
System.out.println(saved.getId()); // is 1l
```

Here's how my setup looks like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY")
public class Entity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

   //...

}

@Repository
public interface SomeRepository extends CrudRepository<Entity, Long> {

}
```

I also tried changing the generation strategy to `AUTO` but then I get

`Table 'embedded-db.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist`

How can I insert data with specific ID while also allowing the id's to be generated?

**UPDATE**

Ok, so I found out that one of the solutions is forcing to use a specific sequence for generating the id and using generation strategy `AUTO` like this:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_seq_gen", sequenceName="actual_seq_name")
private Long id;
```

However I use `mariaDb` for my test env and it does not support sequences, so this solution does not work for me. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the error because `AUTO` means the JPA implementation will:

> ...pick an appropriate strategy for the particular database.

([Source](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html))

Which, for the database you're using (not sure which one?), means hibernate looks in a pre-defined table for the next ID value to use.

As you are setting the IDs manually, remove the `@GeneratedValue` annotation from your variable.

Comment: It works when I insert it with ID, but I also need it to generate id's when they are not provided. As for database, I really can't tell as for testing locally I use MariaDb, and in production it's on amazon cloud that runs on who knows what.

Comment: @Benedictus then that's a subtly different problem (and not something you mentioned in your original question!). As fartpig's answer states, a pragmatic solution would be to have an `AbstractEntity` class, then have two child classes with different id allocation behaviour. (I hope you have a good strategy to avoid collisions!!!)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the parent and child class to support this function. You defined a abstract class with the no id member class, and have the two JPA child class, those map to the same table, but the id strategy is different. So in your code, when you want to set the id , you can use the no @GeneratedValue one. And the other one with @GeneratedValue can support the auto increment case.